# Handling a lots of selects (dropdown lists)

Tags: php, html

Let's say, that i have users stored in a database, identified by an id (an integer primary key). All the users have a multiple choice attribute, for example privileges on a site (Admin, Member, Administrator etc...). I would like to create a php admin page, where i can select for each user his/her privileges, and all users at one page (or at least more users at one page):

```
Tom   [_privileges_v_]
Ed    [_privileges_v_]
Lisa  [_privileges_v_]
...
```

How would it efficient to do?

if i print the dropdowns with the name attribute set as the id of the record, then how could i access them through php?

```
<select name="12323">
    <option value="admin">admin</option>
    <option value="user">user</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="4323">
    <option value="admin">admin</option>
    <option value="user">user</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then after i post this form, my `$_POST` array will contain a `$_POST["12323"]` and a `$_POST["4323"]` member.

**How could i make something like this, so i could iterate through the `$_POST` values?**

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output a select box like this

```
<select name="user_4323">
    <option value="admin">admin</option>
    <option value="user">user</option>
    ...
</select>

<input name="otherinp" value=""/>
```

in case your form has another input.... then in php code you can do

```
foreach($_POST AS $name=>$value) {
  if (strpos($name, "user_")===0){
     $userid = str_replace("user_","",$name);
     //Do st with userid
  }
}

//Work with orther input $_POST['']
```

Answer (score 1):

Either fetch all the users again and loop through their IDs, then check if there is a post value linked to it, or loop through all the post values.

> ```
> foreach($_POST AS $name=>$value) {
>   echo "Selection box with name {$name} has value {$value}";
> }
> ```